# Shell Script to Display Directories and Contents in a List

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

**Shell Script to Display Directories and Contents in a List**

I have a folder called `Projects` and within that folder I have 5 projects. For the sake of this question I'm just going to keep it simple and say that they are labeled like: (Project1, Project2, etc...). When I run `ls` on the folder I get this: (re-labeled for simplicity):

```
Project1  Project2  Project3  Project4  Project5
```

Within these 5 folders, I have 1 .txt file in each directory. How can I create a shell script to list the contents of the folders like this:

```
1. Project1
     > readme.txt

2. Project2
     > readme.txt

3. Project3
     > readme.txt

4. Project4
     > readme.txt

5. Project5
     > readme.txt
```

So basically list the directories with a counter and list the sub-directories under the parent folders.

P.S. The symbol used under the folder name doesn't have to be a '>' , I just used that so it didn't create bullets when using '-'.

Comment: The `tree` command does this. You might have to install it first.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I never heard of `tree`  but when looking at it, It looks way cooler than how I organized it in the example lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to display the information like you are asking would be to use the `$ tree` command from the directory that you want to see all the contents in a hierarchical form.

if not already installed (if using linux it should be)

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install tree
```

if using mac

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install tree
```

This command will display all directories, sub directories below the dir you run the `tree` command from

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

topdir='/tmp/shell-bash.DmgIjp5V'
readme='README.txt'
i=0

for pathname in "$topdir"/*/"$readme"; do
        project="$(basename "$(dirname "$pathname")")"
        printf '%d. %s\n\t- %s\n\n' "$(( ++i ))" "$project" "$readme"
done
```

Test setup:

```
bash-4.4$ mkdir Project{1..5}
bash-4.4$ touch Project{1..5}/README.txt
```

Running it:

```
bash-4.4$ sh script.sh
1. Project1
        - README.txt

2. Project2
        - README.txt

3. Project3
        - README.txt

4. Project4
        - README.txt

5. Project5
        - README.txt
```

Details:

The script simply looks for all `README.txt` files two levels below `$topdir` (this would be your `Projects` directory) and iterates over these.

The `project` variable will hold the name of the project directory under `$topdir`.

The `printf` statement formats and outputs the data according to you specification.

I'm using `basename` and `dirname` here, but some people thinks using variable substitutions are better (it's certainly faster). However, I'm keeping them in for clarity.